# monitor all changes to files on UNIX system

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, filesystems, monitoring

I'm trying to figure out what changes to disk an app does.. and it's very messy.
I'd like a way to monitor my entire file system for a few seconds to know which files have been accessed and written to. I thought of checking the modified date.. but of course it takes ages to do that for every file... there must be a cleverer way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out `fs_usage` (shows all filesystem activity), `creatbyproc.d` (just file creation), `filebyproc.d` (just file opens), `opensnoop` (similar, different format), and `rwsnoop` (reads and writes).

Answer (score 1):

For Linux, you'd check into 'inotify'.  Quick research indicates the same tech for OSX is called 'kqueue'.  It hooks into the filesystem and fires when events happen.

As usual, IBM has [an excellent article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html).

Comment: Might want to fix the link

Comment: Try this link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html